# Quick Sort using java

Tags: java, quicksort, array-algorithms

***This program is showing errors on compilation,can someone suggest what's wrong?***

***The main class:***

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Sortingpro {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of elements");
        int a=input.nextInt();
        int A[]=new int[a];
        System.out.println("Enter the elements");
        for(int i=0;i<a;i++){
            A[i]=input.nextInt();
        }
        sort quick=new sort(A,a);
        quick.display(A,a);
    }
}
```

***The sorting class:***

```
public class sort {
    int A[],size;
    sort(int a[],int s){
        this.A=a;
        this.size=s;
        quickSort(a,1,s);
    }
    void quickSort(int a[],int p,int r){
        while(p<r){
            int q;
            q=Partition(A,p,r);
            quickSort(A,p,q-1);
            quickSort(A,q+1,r);
        }
    }

    int Partition(int a[],int p,int r)
    {
        int x=a[r];
        int i=p-1;
        for(int j=p;j<r;j++){
            if(a[j]<=x){
                i+=1;
                int temp=a[i];
                a[i]=a[j];
                a[j]=temp;
            }
        }
        int temp=a[i+1];
        a[i+1]=a[r];
        a[r]=temp;
        return i=1;
    };
    void display(int A[],int size){
        this.A=A;
        this.size=size;
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
            System.out.println(A);
        }
    }

}
```

Exception.

```
*****The sorting algorithm used is from CLRS.
      I am getting the following errors through Netbeans:
      Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
      at sortingpro.sort.Partition(sort.java:31)
      at sortingpro.sort.quickSort(sort.java:23)
      at sortingpro.sort.<init>(sort.java:17)
      at sortingpro.Sortingpro.main(Sortingpro.java:26)

      Can you please elaborate on these errors and the remedial methods to be undertaken to solve                    the problem? Also any better methods to implement this program,coding wise?
```

Any suggestions on the algorithm are also welcome.However i would prefer the essence of the program to be maintained.

---

Comment: An exception is not "errors on compilation". It means it must have compiled.

Comment: You have an execution exception 'ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException' at sortingpro.sort.Partition(sort.java:31). You are trying to access a index in your array that is negative or bigger than your array.

Comment: If you Google "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" and the look at the line whose number is pointed out in the stack trace, the nature of the problem should become clear.

Answer (score 2):

That's the stack trace says:

You called quick sort with max size like if i entered 10 elements, you called s with 10

```
quickSort(a,1,s);
```

This in turn calls

```
q=Partition(A,p,r);
```

With r as 10, which in turn uses array[r]

Now array starts with index 0 and goes until r-1 in your case and hence you are getting ArrayIndexOutOfBound exception. So call your quicksort method with s-1 as last parameter and 0 as start index i.e.

```
quickSort(a,0,s-1);
```

Also in your recursive solution, you are using while loop which should be if. So your quick sort becomes:

```
void quickSort(int a[],int p,int r){
    if(p<r){
        int q;
        q=Partition(A,p,r);
        quickSort(A,p,q-1);
        quickSort(A,q+1,r);
    }
}
```

Comment: That would throw StackOverflow

Comment: That's followup. OP's question is why AIOOB and not wrong logic or something and you can't expect one to see the future or logic behind the scene.

Comment: Anyways i have updated the answer. OP is using while instead of if.